# Issues in Importing CSV file and making database using SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, import-from-csv

I am really new to SQL/similar things and I am trying to make a database iris.db from iris.csv file. I am running the following thing but getting this:

```
hmi$ ls
data.csv    iris.csv    xh.pdf      z.R     z.Rout
hmi$ sqlite3 iris.db
SQLite version 3.7.16.1 2013-03-29 13:44:34
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import "./iris.csv" iris
Error: no such table: iris
sqlite>
```

Could anyone say, why it's saying no such table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the table `IRIS` with something like this first:

```
CREATE TABLE iris (SomeNum INTEGER, Description TEXT);
```

before you do `.import`

Comment: `.mode csv` changes the separator to a comma.

Comment: @CL Thank you for the tip - I have updated the answer accordingly.